# Android studio : How to loop through JSON objects within another JSON object

Tags: android, json

So i have a Pizza object with three String parameters (name, ingredients, image).
And i have a JSON string in the format :

```
{"Meat pizza":{"Ingredients":"cheese,meat","image":"meat"},"Cheese pizza":{"Ingredients":"cheese","image":"cheese"}}
```

Which i assume is JSON objects within a JSON object.
I'm using Volley library and so far i came up with this:

```
private RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
private String url ="http://daviddurand.info/D228/pizza/";
public ArrayList<Pizza> listPizza(){
    final ArrayList<Pizza> list=new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject obj = null;
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys();
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            String key = iter.next();
                            try {
                                Pizza pizza=new Pizza();
                                Object value = obj.get(key);
                                //fill the Pizza object with data
                                pizza.setName();
                                pizza.setIngredients();
                                pizza.setImage();
                                //insert it into the list
                                list.add(pizza);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // Something went wrong!
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error
        }
    });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return list;
    }
```

Which as you may have guessed already does nothing so far since i have no idea how to get the data to fill the Pizza object..

Note : it's worth to mention that i can't modify how the data is created seeing as how i'm forced into using it from [here](http://daviddurand.info/D228/pizza/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this , You can get inside JSONObject from JSONObject

```
 Object value = obj.get(key);
  //fill the Pizza object with data
   pizza.setName(key);
  JSONObject jsonobject2 =  obj.getJSONObject(key);
    pizza.setIngredients(jsonobject2.getString("ingredients"));
    pizza.setImage(jsonobject2.getString("image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can follow this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/) And I suggest you to use an Array of objects instead Object of objects. Like this Form :

```
[
    {
    "name" : "Ravi Tamada", 
    "email" : "ravi8x@gmail.com",
    "phone" : {
        "home" : "08947 000000",
        "mobile" : "9999999999"
    }
    },
    {
    "name" : "Tommy", 
    "email" : "tommy@gmail.com",
    "phone" : {
        "home" : "08946 000000",
        "mobile" : "0000000000"
    }
    }
]
```

It's much Easier. I Hope this would be useful.

Comment: Using an array of objects would have been delightful, but i'm afraid i have no choice here, seeing how i'm required to get the data from here http://daviddurand.info/D228/pizza/